# Add simple array to Collection

Tags: php, laravel

in laravel this method is return `Collection` type of result:

```
$all_currency = CurrencyType::lists('currency_type', 'id');
```

Result:

```
Collection {#687 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => "EUR"
    2 => "CHF"
  ]
}
```

now and i want to add `-1 => "USD"` to that. but i cant do it. my solution create nested array into that. for example:

```
$all_currency->push (["-1"=>"11"]);
```

Result:

```
Collection {#687 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    1 => "EUR"
    2 => "CHF"
    3 => array:1 [▼
      -1 => "USD"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use array, you can try to convert collection to an array with [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray) method:

```
$all_currency = CurrencyType::pluck('currency_type', 'id')->toArray();
$all_currency['-1'] = '11';
```

If you need to use collection, use [put()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-put) helper:

```
$all_currency = CurrencyType::pluck('currency_type', 'id')->put('-1', '11');
```

Also, `lists()` is deprecated and will be removed in future, use `pluck()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cast the collection to array before adding the currency?

Otherwise, it might help to check out the interface of the Collection class. Since you didn't mention it, it could be Doctrine or Propel or something else?

You then might find out, that there is a special function for adding a key-value pair, since pushing a value, adds that value (an array in your case) to the collection which is not what you want.

There might be no way of adding a value to a specific key index -1, that all depends on which ORM you are actually using and it's implementation.

//edit:

It seems the correct method is put and the code should look like this:

```
$all_currency->push (-1, "11");
```

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_put

Comment: i dont have any class definition of that, and that is laravel methods to get name and id from database to create simple `select` html tag.

Comment: Ok I'm going on a leap here and assume this is the class you're using: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html

Note the put method:
    
    put( mixed $key, mixed $value)
    Put an item in the collection by key.

Now all you do is

    $all_currency->put (-1, "11");

Answer (score 0):

Use the `put()` method on your collection:

```
$all_currency->put(-1, "USD");
```

You can see all available methods for collections here: [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#available-methods)